# Exception for ns4 not resolved

Tags: soap, soap-client, suds

I am trying to run a python script that uses soapclient.

I am running into the following exception. I googled around and couldn't get any details related to this exception.

Can anyone provide inputs on how to overcome the exception?

```
request = self.search_soapclient.factory.create('ns4:SearchRequest')

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 232, in create
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\resolver.py", line 107, in find
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\resolver.py", line 129, in root
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\resolver.py", line 194, in qualify
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\xsd\__init__.py", line 56, in qualify
Exception: prefix (ns4) not resolved
```

Comment: Where do you tell it what ns4 is?

Comment: @PaulTomblin - isnt ns4 resolution default with suds client?how does one specify what ns4 is?

Comment: How are you creating the connection?  Do you have a WSDL?  Is it valid?  If you create your Client and print it, do you see "ns4:SearchRequest" as one of the types?